# Leaked window error from alert box in landscape mode

Tags: android, memory-leaks, alert

I've got a full screen, portrait activity as defined below.

In manifest:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".CameraActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

and

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

The `OnCreate` method of this activity simply invokes an alert box with, YES and NO buttons. My problem is that when the phone is kept in landscape the alert box crashes and I get the leaked window error displayed below.

```
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286): Activity com.eyepax.rdms.CameraActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4058c508 that was originally added here
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.eyepax.rdms.CameraActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4058c508 that was originally added here
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:277)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:288)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at com.eyepax.rdms.CameraActivity$CameraTask.onPreExecute(CameraActivity.java:177)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at com.eyepax.rdms.CameraActivity.onActivityResult(CameraActivity.java:127)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4094)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2905)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1847)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1042)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4268)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-06 15:26:01.590: E/WindowManager(6286):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because the activity will be recreated when the device is turned to `LANDSCAPE` mode. So it is throwing window bad token.

Just try adding the following lines of code in your **manifest**.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: This should not be used because of various issues. Android sdk site says "Note: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications."

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Comment: Please have a look here as well, in case you havent http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html